# Arbitrariness of inner products in discrete differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, graph-theory, inner-products, discrete-calculus

In some sources (see for instance [Discrete Calculus, Grady (2010)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-84996-290-2)
, [Discrete Differential Forms for Computational Modeling, in Discrete Differential Geometry 38, M. Desbrun, E. Kanso, Y. Tong (2008)](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-7643-8621-4_16)), the inner products between $k$-chains for the different $k$ are obtained using the star Hodge operator. Therefore, the inner-products for the different values of $k$ are not independent.

For instance, in section **2.3.3 Primal and Dual Complexes** of Grady's book, it is mentioned that the inner products can be fully determined from the construction of dual complexes. As far as I can tell, this approach is equivalent to the definition of a star Hodge operator when the simplicial complex is a combinatorial manifold.

But I am interested in the field of complex networks where we basically deal with arbitrary graphs which, in general, are not combinatorial manifolds. Hence, I started to look for other references.

In [Hodge Laplacians On Graphs, SIAM Review 62 3 L-H. Lim (2020)](https://doi.org/10.1137/18M1223101), however, (see Pag. 691), an inner product between arbitrary $k$-chains $f,g\in L_{\wedge}^2(K_{k+1})$ is introduced

$$
\langle f,g\rangle_V = \sum_{i_0<i_1<...<i_k} w_{i_0i_1...i_k} f(i_0,i_1,...,i_k)g(i_0,i_1,...,i_k)
$$

As far as I can tell, besides the fact that they should define positive definite inner products, there is no relation between the inner products for the different values of $k$. Although I am not sure, it seems that the inner product between $k$-chains can be independently chosen from the inner product between $q$-chains for any $q\neq k$.

Hence, here I have two questions:

1. Can the inner products for the different values of $k$ be independently chosen?
2. Can we always define these inner products in terms of a star Hodge operator? Or Hodge star operators can be only used for combinatorial manifolds?

Kind regards